# BigInteger FormatException

Tags: c#

In my program, I get a `FormatException` with the message `The value could not be parsed` on the following line:

```
c = BigInteger.Parse("" + Math.Pow(b, 3));
```

The exception occurs when b = 99000, but if I manually replace b with 99000, the exception doesn't occur. I have also tested it with b = 99001, and other higher values but I don't get the error.

Comment: where is `b` defined? and how?

Comment: @noctis b is just in a for loop from 1 to around 1million

Comment: how you define it ? can you post that line? is it `BigInteger b =0;` or is it `var b = something` or `int b = 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying cause is that `Math.Pow` operates on doubles, not integral data types.  By default, [`Double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns only 15 digits of precision, and the double data type can only store a maximum of 17 digits of precision internally.

When b=100,000, b<sup>3</sup> = 1,000,000,000,000,000 (16 digits), and the conversion to a string will return the result as `1E+15`.  [`BigInteger.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can only parse integral values (optional whitespace, followed by a sign, followed by 1 or more numbers), and will throw a FormatException when the string value `"1E+15"` is provided as an argument.

A solution is to avoid `Math.Pow` entirely, and to instead use [`BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This approach avoids conversions to double entirely, and can exponentiate arbitrarily large integers.

With this change, your code might resemble something like this:

```
BigInteger c;
for (BigInteger b = 1; b < 1000000; b++)
{
   c = BigInteger.Pow(b, 3);
   // c stores b^3 as a BigInteger
}
```

Comment: @drf out of interest, will a BigInteger be able to hold a 29-digit number?

Comment: @JamesMonger Yes -- BigInteger values are limited only by available memory.  In practice, this could easily be hundreds of thousands of digits on a modern PC.

Answer (score 0):

Weird ... This seems to work for me, and you were right about the string in parse.

```
BigInteger c;
long b = 9000;
c = BigInteger.Parse("" + Math.Pow(b, 3));
```

No errors thrown ...

As for codemonkeh comment about the `ToString()`, you could also do this

```
BigInteger d = new BigInteger(Math.Pow(b, 3));
```

Assuming you are not running in a loop that will create heaps of those ...

Comment: Math.Pow returns a double

Comment: and what would this return : ("" + Math.Pow(b, 3)) :)

Comment: That returns a string, which the Parse method requires

Comment: Why not just use `Math.Pow(b, 3).ToString()`?

Comment: Or even better, `new BigInteger(Math.Pow(b, 3))`

Comment: @Noctis if you are running in a loop using either the constructor or the Parse method will create multiple instances

Comment: Yep, this is why i wouldn't suggest it ... but I don't have his code to begin with ... :)